# How to append values to a text area using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I have a text area which is generating randomly with different id

```
<textarea id=t"+i+" placeholder="+["Html","CSS","Js"][i]+" rows=9></textarea>
```

This text area is having ids from t0 to t3 what i want to do is that i want to append values to this text area using javascript how can i do that?. The value generation should be happen before creating dom

Comment: You can use jquery's `val();` function for this https://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: I want to append this how can i do that?.

Comment: @Companjo $('a').click(function() //this will apply to all anchor tags { $('#t' + id).val('some value'); }) this is what will happen but what i want to do is that i want to append the value before creating DOM itself how can i do that?.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're generating the html. If so, you can use `attribute selector` with *begins-with* operator.

```
$('[id^=t]').val('some value');
```

Note that this sets value for all elements which have their ids beginning with `t`. So be careful when using ids starting with `t` and if you know before hand the number after `t`, then you can just target that element.

```
$('#t' + id).val('some value');
```

Comment: Should i use this with the form element or should i use it in a script tag?.

Comment: @geekishfellow in a script tag

Comment: Looks like a jquery function is it so?.

Comment: $('a').click(function() //this will apply to all anchor tags
{ 
   $('#t' + id).val('some value');
}) this is what will happen but what i want to do is that i want to append the value before creating dom itself how can i do that?.